# Alternative Way for Post Form in Order to Call Two Functions (Javascript to PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

First of all i have a process which user selects a file to upload in order to finish a form.

That process is working with no problems.

Second, I have other process that also needs that file to send it attached to an email. This process also is working but the problem starts here.

Both processes make queries on a database, that's why they are separated.

According this thread's solution:

[Take Input Type File (HTML) to JavaScript and Send an Email Using PHPmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797407/take-input-type-file-html-to-javascript-and-send-an-email-using-phpmailer/40799025#40799025)

You have to use a form "Post" to send the information to the PHP file and finish the process, something like this:

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sendMailForm" action="finish.php">
    <textarea name="descripcion" style="min-width: 70%" required></textarea>     
     <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" required/><br><br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">TERMINAR</button>
</form>
```

Thanks to this form i can take the information of this form and use it on my PHP file to save the information and the file on database.

But the same file that this PHP file uses i need it to another different process, here is the function:

```
$("#sendMailForm").submit(function(evt){     
   evt.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); 
   SendMail(formData);
   return false;
 });

function SendMail(formData){
$.ajax({
 url: 'SendMail.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: formData,
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 contentType: false,
 enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
 processData: false,
 success: function (response) {
   alert(response);
 }
   });
}
```

Also this process works with no problems.

But my goal is the next one:

- When the process is finished (user clicks on the form's button) i need to activate both processes of both PHP files but the post method only let me use one function at time.
- So, is there a way to use this post form to achieve my goal?
- Or, Is there and alternative way to post form in this case?

I tried adding the call of the other function with onclick

```
 <button type="submit" onclick="SendMail()" class="btn btn-primary">TERMINAR</button>
```

But only works the post call to the PHP file in the form.

I hope you can help my with this issue.

Thank for your time and attention.

Comment: are you trying to execute 2 async calls and then only execute a callback? is that the goal of this exercise?

Comment: also it would be great to be able to see the php code as well

Comment: Have you tried removing `evt.preventDefault();` in the submit function? This is preventing the form from executing normally -- in other words, submitting to PHP

Comment: The order doesn't matter, i only want that both processes works and only i can make one work at time due the post form restriction to one process at submit.

Comment: Remove `evt.preventDefault();` and `return false` from your `submit` function.

Comment: The PHP codes were not posted because these are processes that works fine, the main problem lies here where i have to call them properly to make both of them work when user submits the form.

Comment: Charlotte and Robyn, thanks for your answers, i'm going to test it. If you have any other idea i'm glad to read it :)