# What is the correct code for getting a file using javascript to php then sending to an email?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using PHPMailer.

My PHP code:

```
 $mail->addAttachment('excuse-letter.docx', "excuse-letter.docx");
 // this code works but i want to know what is the code when a person will upload a file.
```

My JavaScript code:

```
 $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      var file = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
      $.post("receive.php", {FFname:FFname,LLname:LLname,file:file});
});
```

Comment: there's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for that

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php the manual knows all

Comment: Split it into two different tasks, first you may want to send an email (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797407/take-input-type-file-html-to-javascript-and-send-an-email-using-phpmailer), then find out how to upload from js and then attach it to your email

Comment: You'll want to `event.preventDefault()` at the bottom of the submit. Also, you want to test, for `isset($_POST['FFname'])` on the PHP page. I'm assuming that's the page you want to post to, with that `$mail` Object. By the way we can't see where that's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @PHPglue hey, is there a way that the submit form in html and  $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) }); in javascript will run at the same time in 1 click?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to get a file in JavaScript and pass it to PHP then PHP will send it to email by the use of PHPmailer?

I got the code of multiple attachment and sending it to an email.

```
for( $ct=0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++){

    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));

    $filename =$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by using the form submit as a validation

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) 
{
 var x = 0;
 var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
 var errr="";
 var lname = document.getElementById("lname");

if (fname == "")
 errr = "first name";
else
  x++;

if (lname == "")
 errr = errr+ " last name";
else
  x++;

if(x==2)
{

   $('concatname').val = fname+" "+lname;

   event.Default(); //go in sample.php

} 

else{

alert("please fill your "+errr );
   event.preventDefault(); //validation

}

});
```

//in my html form

```
<form action='sample.php'>

<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

<input type="text" id="concatname" name="concatname" hidden>

<input type="submit">
```

in my sample.php

i REQUEST all the datas and attachments

```
$name = $_REQUEST['concatname'];

 $mail->body($name);

for( $ct=0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++){

$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));

$filename =$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
}}
```